# Color format cell containing string and numeric values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column in an Excel sheet with both string and numeric values which is city and zip code.

I have tried using vba code to separate the city and zip code which worked fine, but then I could not get the conditional format to work.

I don't want two separate columns, but I want vba code/ color format that color my cells "light green" when the zipcode is greater than 5999 (danish zip code is from 1-10000).

My sheet gets updated once every month or week so the solution should update new cells to be light green .

I have attached an example of the way I want it to look like:

[image]

I tried color format like this but also with `left(p6;1)="8"`:

[image]

kind regards

additionel question for advanced colorcoding
[image]

Comment: `val(left(a1,4))>5999` ?

Comment: nope and there is no function called val. i tried left(a1;4)>5999 but that did not work either

Comment: `value`, not val then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is in columns `A:C`, then in `Conditional Formatting` under `Use a formula to determine which cells to format` use:

**Comma**

```
=AND(NOT(ISERROR(VALUE(LEFT($C1,FIND(" ",$C1)-1)))),IFERROR(VALUE(LEFT($C1,FIND(" ",$C1)-1))>5999,0))
```

**Semi-colon**

```
=AND(NOT(ISERROR(VALUE(LEFT($C1;FIND(" ";$C1)-1))));IFERROR(VALUE(LEFT($C1;FIND(" ";$C1)-1))>5999;0))
```

**Images**

[image]

[image]

Comment: The UK also uses commas, and we did even when we were in the EU! I think Australia and Canada do too.

Comment: @SJR: Sorry, will remove.

Comment: Don't worry, it was just a casual observation that's it's not just a US/European thing, but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: this worked in the beginning but for some reason it stop working when i apply it in color formatting even though that the formula calculates true and false correct

Comment: The `$` sign is mandatory so is `C` i.e. the column string of the last of the three columns. And you select the last of the options in your image. Maybe check the `Applies to`.

Comment: @MathiesSkovJeppesen: I've added images to my answer.

Comment: my boss was pleased but want to hier i i could add a feature. the extra feature is like in the images. the color has to depend as before with >5999, but i must not overrule the other formatting colors that are green as in the images. i thought about making and if statement before the code so it would be if(AND(NOT(ISERROR(VALUE(LEFT($C1;FIND(" ";$C1)-1))));IFERROR(VALUE(LEFT($C1;FIND(" ";$C1)-1))>5999;0))) but this did not work. do you know if itis possible to make a solution that have color format like in the pic? ps the color are mad automatically, without colorformatting

Answer (score 0):

yes i did all mandatory things and check it in the sheet that it calculates everything tur or false like in the picture, but when i copypaste the formula into the color formatting it want color the cells if it is true. this is danish sand=True falsk=false see link/image for the screenshot of the sheet with the formula applied
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iscaS.png)